# I am getting the following error.Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'files' of undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, ajax, ethereum, ipfs

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
      const ipfs = window.IpfsApi({
        host: 'ipfs.infura.io',
        port: 5001,
        protocol: 'https'
      });
      const Buffer = window.IpfsApi().Buffer;
      const ContractAddress = "0xf21ac1844861a76754d7c3db29067cb0970fb8b5";
      if (typeof web3 === "undefined") {
        return showError("Please install MetaMask.");
      }
      const contract = web3.eth.contract(Config.getContractABI()).at(ContractAddress);

      function uploadCertificate() {
        //TODO: Write the Logic behind Uploading a Certificate to IPFS and adding the information to the Blockchain
        let filesDiv = $("#certificateForUpload");
        if (filesDiv[0].files.length === 0) {
          return showError("Please select a file.");
        }

        let fileReader = new FileReader();
        fileReader.onload = function() {
          let fileBuffer = Buffer.from(fileReader.result);
          ipfs.files.add(fileBuffer, (err, result) => {
            if (err) {
              return showError(err);
            }

            if (result) {
              let ipfsHash = result[0].hash;
              contract.addCertificate(ipfsHash, function(err, result) {
                if (err) {
                  return showError("There was error with smart contract: $(err)")
                }
                showInfo("Certificate $(ipfsHash) was <b> successfully added.</b> to the Registry.")
              })
            }

          });
        };
        fileReader.readAsArrayBuffer(filesDiv[0].files[0]);

      }
```

Comment: There's two references to `files` in your source. Which one caused the error? `ipfs.files` or `filesDiv[0].files` ? Share the full error

Comment: filesDiv[0] is causing the error.

Comment: Then `$("#certificateForUpload")` is not returning what you think it is. Maybe you don't have an element with this `id=""` attribute?

Comment: s.
(anonymous) @ book.js:4
(anonymous) @ book.js:5
certificates.js:13 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'files' of undefined
    at HTMLInputElement.uploadCertificate (certificates.js:13)
    at HTMLInputElement.dispatch (jquery-3.3.1.min.js:2)
    at HTMLInputElement.y.handle (jquery-3.3.1.min.js:2)
This is the full error.

Comment: console.log(filesDiv). ==>see in the console what you are getting 

                                                                                                                filesDiv[0].files // probably you dont have files at filesDiv[0]

Comment: ReferenceError: $ is not defined
    at Object.<anonymous> (c:\Users\Personal\Downloads\CertificatesRegistry\CertificatesRegistry\certificates.js:1:1)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1135:14)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1158:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:986:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:879:14)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:71:12)
    at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:47
certificates.js:1

Comment: `$` suggest you are using jquery, and that error suggests you are trying to do this on node.js, where there's usually no jQuery / DOM. Do you expect to be able to run your script on node.js but interact with a browser DOM? This is basically not possible. You need some kind of API